# Run expect script from other shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, expect

My target  is to create the `/var/tmp/add_user.bash` script from `/var/tmp/create_script_add_user.bash` script
and run the expect script (`add_user.bash`) from `create_script_add_user.bash` script.

The problem is that when I run the script `add_user.bash` from `create_script_add_user.bash`, then expect gets stuck on the question:

```
      Proceed? n)
```

It looks like expect can't see the question from standard output.
But when I run the script `/var/tmp/add_user.bash`, then it works fine.

Why can't expect run from the other script? And how to solve this issue?

#### Contents of `/var/tmp/create_script_add_user.bash`

```
   #!/bin/bash


   echo '#!/bin/bash


   add_user=`cat << EOF
   set timeout -1
   spawn /var/tmp/add_user.bash user_name=OBAMA
   expect n)   { send "yes\r" }
   expect eof
   EOF`

    /usr/local/bin/expect -c  "$add_user"

    '> /var/tmp/add_user.bash

    chmod +x /var/tmp/add_user.bash

    #need sleep for 5 seconds
    ( sleep 5 ; /var/tmp/add_user.bash ) &
```

#### Contents of `/var/tmp/add_user.bash`

```
 #!/bin/bash

 add_user=`cat << EOF
 set timeout -1
 spawn /var/tmp/add_user.bash user_name=OBAMA
 expect n)   { send "yes\r" }
 expect eof
 EOF`

 /usr/local/bin/expect -c  "$add_user"
```

Comment: thx Vonbrand - did you think it will be better to migrate my question to stack-overflow ?

Comment: Also asked on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/495699/30957)

Comment: hi gilles can you consider to deliver my question to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution for the problem

need to run the /var/tmp/add_user.bash without the process " & "

example

```
       #need sleep for 5 seconds

       sleep 5

       source /var/tmp/add_user.bash
```

now expect get the "**n)**" string and send "**y**" as answer